# Java Bytes for AES Decryption

Tags: java, aes

I am trying to do brute force AES decryption using Java.  The cypher text is 160 hex characters.  I know the last half of the 128 bit AES encryption key (all 0s).  How can I make a loop to test all the permutations of the first half in Java using byte arrays?

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

64 nested loops, each from 0 to 255. It will take a while to run ;-) I suggest you calculate or extrapolate exactly how long. You might get quite a surprise.

Comment: isnt there a flaw that can take off a few bits? Still take you a while, but it should knock off a few million years. In fact there is - http://web.townsendsecurity.com/bid/41904/AES-Encryption-Flaw-Calm-Down

Comment: Actually, as it is a 128-bit key (not 128 byte) of which the half is known, you need only 8 such nested loops, which will be faster. (Still likely too long for an off-the-shelf computer without parallelization.)